# UPDATE trigger leads to Deadlock - Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, triggers

Mysql Version: 5.6

I have a trigger on a table which has a bunch of conditions. But, the trigger does some selects at the top. I am getting deadlocks on some.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS pieces_after_update;

CREATE TRIGGER pieces_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON pieces FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @COMPANYID = (SELECT company_id FROM skus where id = NEW.sku_id);
    SET @CLOSINGSTOCK = (SELECT closing_stock FROM skus_warehouses WHERE sku_id=NEW.sku_id AND warehouse_id=NEW.warehouse_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1);
    SET @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK = (SELECT closing_pending_stock FROM skus_warehouses WHERE sku_id=NEW.sku_id AND warehouse_id=NEW.warehouse_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1);
    IF (@CLOSINGSTOCK IS NULL)
    THEN
        SET @CLOSINGSTOCK=0;
    END IF;

    ##movement from putaway_pending to putaway_done for good stock
    IF (NEW.stock_status_id=4 AND NEW.is_bad_stock=0 AND OLD.stock_status_id=3) 
    THEN        
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Stock Added by putaway of serial no ', NEW.id), 1, @CLOSINGSTOCK+1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK); 
    END IF; 

    ##movement from putaway_done to blocked for an order/outward entity
    IF(NEW.stock_status_id=5  AND NEW.is_bad_stock=0 AND OLD.stock_status_id=4)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Stock blocked for serial no ', NEW.id, ' for ', NEW.outward_entity_type, ' id ', NEW.outward_entity_id), -1, @CLOSINGSTOCK-1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK); 
    END  IF;

    ##movement from BLOCKED to PUTAWAY_DONE for an order/outward entity. Unblocking case, needs adjustment entry in SkuW
    IF(NEW.stock_status_id=4  AND OLD.stock_status_id=5 AND NEW.is_bad_stock=0)
    THEN        
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Stock UNblocked for serial no ', NEW.id, ' for ', NEW.outward_entity_type, ' id ', NEW.outward_entity_id), 1, @CLOSINGSTOCK+1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK); 
    END  IF;  

    ##movement from PUTAWAY_DONE to PICKED (missed BLOCKED) for an order/outward entity
    IF(NEW.stock_status_id=6  AND NEW.is_bad_stock=0 AND OLD.stock_status_id=4)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Stock blocked & picked for serial no ', NEW.id, ' for ', NEW.outward_entity_type, ' id ', NEW.outward_entity_id), -1, @CLOSINGSTOCK-1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK); 
    END  IF;

    ##movement from PICKED to PUTAWAY_DONE for an order/outward entity. Unpicking case, needs adjustment entry in SkuW
    IF(NEW.stock_status_id=4  AND OLD.stock_status_id=6 AND NEW.is_bad_stock=0)
    THEN        
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Stock Unpicked & Unblocked for serial no ', NEW.id, ' for ', OLD.outward_entity_type, ' id ', OLD.outward_entity_id), 1, @CLOSINGSTOCK+1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK); 
    END  IF; 

    ##movement from PUTAWAY_DONE/good_stock to PUTAWAY_PENDING/bad_stock
    IF(NEW.is_bad_stock=1 AND OLD.stock_status_id=4 AND NEW.stock_status_id=3)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Stock marked as BADSTOCK for serial no ', NEW.id), -1,@CLOSINGSTOCK-1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK);
    END IF;

    ##movement from PUTAWAY_DONE to INVALIDATED
    IF(OLD.stock_status_id=4 AND NEW.stock_status_id=10)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO skus_warehouses(sku_id, warehouse_id, company_id, comment, stock_changed_by, closing_stock, closing_pending_stock)
        VALUES(NEW.sku_id, NEW.warehouse_id, @COMPANYID, CONCAT_WS(' - ','Invalidated serial no ', NEW.id), -1,@CLOSINGSTOCK-1, @CLOSINGPENDINGSTOCK);
    END IF;

END; //
```

I know I am getting deadlocks on the trigger because this is what I found in SHOW INNODB ENGINE STATUS

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 635520869854, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 5, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 1625 lock struct(s), heap size 177704, 7983 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2085967891, OS thread handle 0x2b5e2d4d1700, query id 503500721288 10.0.10.59 primary_db_user Creating sort index
SET @CLOSINGSTOCK = (SELECT closing_stock FROM skus_warehouses WHERE sku_id=NEW.sku_id AND warehouse_id=NEW.warehouse_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 139169 page no 7248658 n bits 216 index `PRIMARY` of table `primary_db`.`skus_warehouses` trx id 635520869854 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 121 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 14; compact format; info bits 0
```

The table skus_warehouses has 100M+ records, but has good indexing. All below queries (which seem to be deadlocking) complete in 0.5 to 1s.

```
SET @CLOSINGSTOCK = (SELECT closing_stock FROM skus_warehouses WHERE sku_id=NEW.sku_id AND warehouse_id=NEW.warehouse_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: A deadlock happens when different transactions each require a resource another transaction had locked. We currently only see "one side". Also, your transaction has 7983 rows locked when it enters the trigger. So the problem is somewhere outside that trigger. Without more of/the complete transaction (e.g. the code that calls the trigger, and the code for the 2nd transaction (if different)/the 2nd entry in innodb status) and indexes (we trust you that they are "good", but we e.g. don't even know the columns for the problematic primary key) we have no starting point to help you find a solution.

Comment: How often do you get deadlocks? One or two once in a while - better to handle those by rerunning the rolled back transaction.